# Magento 2: How to get multiple selection attibute as list on list.phtml

Tags: magento2

I've added a multiple select attribute to my products an now I'm trying to show the result on "list.phtml" template. (Product list).

Im getting all the values like this:

```
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_name')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

This returns a String with all the values, but I need it to be an array so I can transform it to a list with individual links.

Any help?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up using:

```
$attribute_string = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

$attribute_array = explode(', ', $attribute_string);
```

Comment: how to set values programmatically?

Comment: But what  if there is a comma already in the values? In this case it is splitting single value as two array items which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Converting object to array.

$data = array($attribute);

Or

$data = (array) $attribute;

Comment: Thanks Jitendra

I ended up using $data = explode(', ', $string);

Answer (score 0):

Complete code to print in list.phtml

```
 <?php
    $attribute_string = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('region')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
    
    $attribute_array = explode(',', $attribute_string);
    echo $attribute_string;  ?>
```